Safari prevents TR with display:none to be reshown using display:block or display:''; UNLESS a JavaScript alert('') is used at the end
As the title says. THIS works on all browsers EXCEPT Safari (iPad).
Safari prevents TR with display:none to be reshown using display:block or display:''; UNLESS a JavaScript alert('') is used at the end.
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
const customerTable = document.getElementById('listTable');

if (searchBox) {
    searchBox.addEventListener('input', function () {
    var numResults = 0;

        const searchValue = searchBox.value.toLowerCase();
        const rows = customerTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const customerName = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent.toLowerCase();
            if (customerName.includes(searchValue)) {
        rows[i].style.display = 'block';
        numResults++;
            } else {
          rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
}
</script>

Somehow THIS fixes it:
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
const customerTable = document.getElementById('listTable');

if (searchBox) {
    searchBox.addEventListener('input', function () {
    var numResults = 0;

        const searchValue = searchBox.value.toLowerCase();
        const rows = customerTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const customerName = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent.toLowerCase();
            if (customerName.includes(searchValue)) {
        rows[i].style.display = 'block';
        numResults++;
            } else {
          rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        alert('Why in the Steve Jobs does this fix anything??');
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ just this one line fixes everything

        return true;
    });
}
</script>

So, essentially what happens -- Safari hides the non matches, and should show the good matches. The issue here is, that when the good matches are set to become visible again, no change occurs.
A change on screen will occur only in two instances:

There is no text at all in the search box

An alert() is added to the bottom of everything, it can be on a timer or alone, whatever the case is, it causes all the elements on the screen that matched to become visible.



Table rows are not (by default) display: block; they're display: table-row. It's a very significant difference.

I'm aware. That doesn't work either.

If an alert(...) is called, it forces a DOM redraw (for some ungodly reason) and everything works, but if I never call alert(...) nothing I do, even with all the redraw tricks tried, nothing works to show those rows again.
